# nodejs open chrome in window with arguments

Tags: node.js

Trying to write my own plugins for gulp. So I've written a gulp task that attempts opens the chrome browser in windows (i'll work on getting working for mac/linux later).

It seems to work except it's not passing in my arguments:

```
/*
 * Open
 */

gulp.task('open', function (done) {
  var uri = 'http://localhost:' + CONFIG.PORT,
       CONFIG.PORT = 8080,

  args = [
    uri,
    '--no-first-run',
    '--no-default-browser-check',
    '--disable-translate',
    '--disable-default-apps',
    '--disable-popup-blocking',
    '--disable-zero-browsers-open-for-tests',
    '--disable-web-security',
    '--new-window',
    '--user-data-dir="C:/temp-chrome-eng"'
  ]
  cp.spawn('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', args);
})
```

How do i get it to accept my arguments it passed in? Am in providing it the wrong arguments?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a quite popular npm module, [opener](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opener), instead which will solve both your issue with arguments and cross platform support.

Instead of finding the browser executable like you are doing, you can simply write:

```
var opener = require('opener')
opener('http://google.com')
```

If you however want to go with your current method, try capturing the output by naming your process and then listening on stderr and stdout:

```
var chrome = cp.spawn ...

chrome.stdout.on('data', function (data) {                                      
    console.log(data.toString())
})

chrome.stderr.on('data', function (data) {                                      
    console.error(data.toString())
})
```

It does work for me on linux if I replace your chrome path with `chromium`.

Comment: trying to roll my own as stated. :(

Comment: I tried out your method on linux, and it worked fine. I added some debugging steps to my answer